# Best way for mapping enum with int

Tags: java, playframework, persistence

I have a little dilemma, what would be better - if i set as field of my entity map:

```
@ManyToMany
Map<SomeEnum, Integer> field;
```

or List and create additional class for mapping enum with int:

```
@ManyToOne
List<WrapperClass> field;
```

and wrapper class:

```
@Entity
class WrapperClass {

  @Basic(optional=false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  public SomeEnum someEnum;

  public int value;
}
```

Comment: what's your purpose for this kind mapping? Enum type instance has a `ordinal()` method to fetch it's int value, which is unique across the same enum type

Comment: And even if you need a specific value to your enums (not the ordinal!), the simplest solution to me seems to be to add an integer field to your enum. `enum Test { int val; FOO(5), BAR(10); public Test(int val) {this.val = val} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if my answer is going to be *really* helpful, since in my opinion, the choice of data structure that you need really depends upon what you're going to use your information for. However, since you haven't provided that, I'll infer some things (probably incorrectly...). I'll update my answer if you provide more information.

Since you appear to want to make a mapping from an `enum` to an `int`, the more natural data structure to use would be the first, that is

```
Map<SomeEnum, Integer> field;
```

simply because that defines a mapping quite nicely. You'll get better lookup times and a data structure that's meant to link a key (in this case `SomeEnum`) to a value (the `Integer`).

With a `List` or a `Set`, the data structure that you're using isn't as naturally suited to finding what value is mapped to by some instance of `SomeEnum`. You'll have to write your own `Comparator` or `compareTo` for your `WrapperClass` and write more code that would already be taken care of for your if you're using `Map<SomeEnum, Integer> field`.

...unless there's some specific reason why you'd need a different way of coding this up? Some constraint that stops you from using this approach?